# How add url_for in custom method in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, module, helper

I am writing a custom form helper and i need a URL path declared in routes but i have this error:

```
    module CustomFormHelpers
      include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
      include ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper
      include ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper
      include ActionView::Helpers::CaptureHelper
      include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper
      include ActionView::Helpers::RawOutputHelper
      include ActionView::Helpers::JavaScriptHelper
      include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper

      def tags
        tags_path
      end

    end
```

```
in routes.rb

resources :tags
```

What do I need include in the module to work

Comment: Please reformat your code within <pre><code> or `` blocks.  Also, the error is not showing up.

Comment: What error?  I don't see one, although I do see a strange word that looks suspiciously like a typo: "rosources".

Comment: Error: undefined local variable or method `_routes' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x106a7c770>

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of [using url_for in a lib folder module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875599/using-url-for-in-a-lib-folder-module)

short answer:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```