# using url_for in a lib folder module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model with a field called "type" and a field called "value". The type field will determine how the "value" is parsed before rendering. I want this to be easily extendible, so I'm putting a variety of "formatter" classes in my lib folder.

One of my "formatters" has a call to url_for:

```
class CustomTypeFormatter 
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers

  def show
    raw sanitize( auto_link( value ) )
  end

  def get_url(page)
    url_for( :controller => :my_controller, :action => :show, :path => page.path )
  end

end
```

The problem is, url_for is raising this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `_routes'
```

I think I'm just missing an include. Does anyone have an idea what it should be?

**UPDATE*****

Here's part of the stack trace:

```
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:131:in `url_for'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:99:in `url_for'
```

So I think it must be some ActiveDispatch dependency, although I cannot figure out

Comment: I think you need to include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Victory!

```
include ActionView::Helpers
include ActionDispatch::Routing
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

via http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/UrlWriter

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to url_for you can use `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` just add in route `:as` like the following example:

```
get "sessions/destroy/:param_id", as: :logout
```

so you can use it as following:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.logout_path(:param_id => your_value)
```

This will do the same as url_for

Hopefully, this would help